Page become unresponsive when running AGChart on array of objects
I am developing one project using Angular 17 and AG Angular Charts. I want to create horizontal bar charts in separate div using same set of data(array of objects). I have implemented below code but it makes page unresponsive. What am I doing wrong here?
Stackblitz Code Link
HTML File
<div style="float:left; border:solid 1px #7CB9E8; border-radius:5px; background-color: white; margin-left: 15%; width:45%; padding: 2%; margin-top: 2%; " *ngFor="let ques of getQues(); let quesIndex = index">
    <ag-charts-angular style="height: 100%;" *ngIf="isBrowser" [options]="options[quesIndex]">
    </ag-charts-angular>

</div>

TS File
@Component({
selector: 'view-survey',
templateUrl: './viewsurvey.component.html',
standalone: true,
imports: [
CommonModule,
AgChartsAngularModule,
],
providers: [],
})
export class ViewSurveyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    public options:AgChartOptions[]=[];
    public isBrowser!: boolean;   

    constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object) {      
        this.isBrowser = isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId);              
    }
    
    ngOnInit() {      
      for(let cntQues=0; cntQues<this.getQues().length; cntQues++)
      { 
        let option:AgChartOptions = {                    
          data: (this.getQues()[cntQues]),
          series: [
            {
              type: "bar",
              direction: "horizontal",
              xKey: "response",
              yKey: "respcnt",
              yName: "Response Count",
            },                
          ],};
        this.options.push(option);
      }}

    ngOnDestroy() {           
    }

    getQues()
    {      
      const arrQues:any[] =
      [{
        0 : [
          {
            response: "Response 1",
            respcnt: 80,                  
          },
          {
            response: "Response 2",
            respcnt: 94,                    
          }],
        },
        {
        1:[
          {
            response: "Response 1",
            respcnt: 70,                  
          },
          {
            response: "Response 2",
            respcnt: 62,                    
          },
          {
            response: "Response 3",
            respcnt: 92,                    
          }]
        }];
      
      return arrQues;
    }
}

Please help me here.

Could you add a reproducible runnable e.g. using stackblitz or other online code running platforms ... makes easy to understand and help

Hi..I have added Stackblitz Code Link at beginning of the page for easier understanding.
